# Why is my head not working on my website? It only shows the alt text

Tags: html, css, header

```
div id="container">
<div id="header">><img src="JBbanner.jpg" width="920" height="125" alt="JB Banner" />
</div>
```

All I can get to display in the container is the alt text the image which is saved in the same folder does not display at all.

I am expecting my header to display on the page it just displays the alternate text instead of the banner which is supposed to display.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check that the image filename is correct.

Comment: Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see why that img isn’t loading?